# Making sense of my load tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, testing, performance-testing

I am trying to test some web services that I have exposed. I have created some web performance tests that emulate user activity. I have put these into a load test, with a step load pattern, with the intent of loading on users to discover the number x of concurrent users that would make the response time go above 10 seconds.

I have tried doing this, but the results...are unexpected. Over 1,000 `500-InternalServerErrors`. Weirdly, however, my avg response time stays largely the same - at an extremely low value (the blue line in this graph), while the number of users increases to a maximum of 200, despite what the graph indicates (red line) and the number of requests/sec also increases (green). Surely this is incorrect, as page response time should go up with these.

[image: Graph]

Can anyone offer any insight as to what might be going on here, and how I might fix it ?

The data set I am working from is a test data set that is tiny, so my only theory is that perhaps all requests are being cached, explaining the snappy response time, but the server is still being inundated, hence the errors.

Apologies for the lack of details - I am new to performance testing. Any questions will be answered straight away. Many thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure the Internal Server Error responses are caused by the number of requests per second? If there is another error, for instance max number of concurrent database connections reached, it would explain the increasing number of requests per second.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I thought this might also be an issue, however my SQL server is configured to allow an infinite amount of concurrent connections, as is my IIS server. Can't think at all about what is causing this.